# PayPal iOS Credit Card not working

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using the code from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

I am able to buy things using Paypal account. However there is no option for me to pay by credit card.

May I know how can I enable the option for paying by credit card?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're not using a supported country for the Credit Card payments.

From their docs:
*Note: Direct Credit Card Payments is only available in a select few countries. Also, see the International Support section for details on the specific currencies supported.*

Further info on supported countries:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments

Comment: My country is Malaysia and it is a supported country for Credit Card payment.